# Jquery Datepicker changing format on reloading the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery DatePicker for my application with the format `dd/mm/yy`. The code i am using to get it is below.

```
$(function(){
    $("#demandStartDate").datepicker({showAnim: 'clip', inline: 'true', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val;  
    $("#goLiveDate").datepicker({showAnim: 'clip', inline: 'true',dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val; 
});
```

when I submit the form, all values including the selected date are supplied to controller as entered. But when form reloads after finishing the task the date fields are filled with dates of different format like Wed `Nov 2013 00.00.00 IST`.

How to get rid of this behavior? I want all the dates as entered by the user (in the default format `dd/mm/yy`) to be filled on reload.

Comment: Please see the updated question Milind.

Comment: It would be great if you can create fiddle for your problem/

Comment: In fiddle it is working fine using reload for a button. But the problem is when using it spring framework I think so.

Comment: I have a doubt, do you need to retain the value of date in the textbox when you relaod?

Comment: Not very necessary Praveen. I can go for clearing those fields on reload. But I am curious about why it is changing the format.

Comment: In your code, at the end of each line .val should be .val()